# Java - executebatch is not working when inserting records to db

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to insert records into my table in MYSQL after extracting the words from a file and stored them in a hashset.

I tried using **executeBatch()** to insert into my db after getting 500 records but when the execution finished, I checked my table and there's no record inserted at all.

Note: When I use **ExecuteUpdate()** then the records will show in my table. But not ExecuteBatch() since I want to insert by batch, not one by one.
May I know what did I do wrong?

Code:

```
public void readDataBase(String path,String word) throws Exception {
        try {

            // Result set get the result of the SQL query

            int i=0;
            // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Setup the connection with the DB
            connect = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://126.32.3.20/fulltext_ltat?"
                            + "user=root&password=root");

            // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
          //  statement = connect.createStatement();
            System.out.print("Connected");
            // Result set get the result of the SQL query

            preparedStatement = connect
                    .prepareStatement("insert IGNORE into  fulltext_ltat.indextable values (default,?, ?) ");

            preparedStatement.setString(  1, path);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, word);
            preparedStatement.addBatch();
            i++;
           // preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            if(i%500==0){
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();

            }




         preparedStatement.close();



            //  writeResultSet(resultSet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            close();
        }

    }
```

This is my loop to call that method(words is just an array that contains the words which is going to be inserted to the table):

```
 for(int i = 1 ; i <= words.length - 1 ; i++ ) {

                    connection.readDataBase(path, words[i].toString());

                }
```

My main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StopWatch stopwatch = new StopWatch();
        stopwatch.start();



        File folder = new File("D:\\PDF1");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                HashSet<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();
                String path = "D:\\PDF1\\" + file.getName();
                try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path))) {

                    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                        PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                        String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                        String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
                        for (String line : lines) {
                            String[] words = line.split(" ");

                            for (String word : words) {
                                uniqueWords.add(word)
                                ;

                            }

                        }
                        // System.out.println(uniqueWords);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Exception while trying to read pdf document - " + e);
                }
                Object[] words = uniqueWords.toArray();



                MysqlAccessIndex connection = new MysqlAccessIndex();

                for(int i = 1 ; i <= words.length - 1 ; i++ ) {

                    connection.readDataBase(path, words[i].toString());

                }

                System.out.println("Completed");

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern for doing batch updates is off.  You should be opening the connection and preparing the statement only once.  Then, iterate multiple times, binding parameters, and add that statement to the batch.

```
// define a collection of paths and words somewhere
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    // presumably you only want to insert so many records
    int LIMIT = 10000;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connect = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://126.32.3.20/fulltext_ltat?"
                + "user=root&password=root");

    String sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO fulltext_ltat.indextable VALUES (default, ?, ?);";
    preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

    for (int i=0; i < LIMIT; ++i) {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, paths.get(i));
        preparedStatement.setString(2, word.get(i));
        preparedStatement.addBatch();
        if (i % 500 == 0) {
            preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        }
    }

    // execute remaining batches
    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    try {
        preparedStatement.close();
        connect.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

One key change I made here is to add logic for when you should stop doing inserts.  Currently, your code looks to have an infinite loop, which means it would run forever.  This is probably not what you were intending to do.

Comment: Which part of my code consist of running the infinite loop?
If you set a limit to 10,000 then if the my hashset contain more than the limit, it wouldn't insert after 10,000 right?

Comment: Oops...you don't have _any_ loop, which is probably the reason for no batches being written out to the database.  So, you need a loop somewhere, but it should be where I have highlighted, and _not_ outside where you open your connection and prepare the insert statement.

Comment: The limit is to set the words that could be inserted for up to 10,000 , am i right?

Comment: Yes, I have up to 10000 records, being inserted in batches of up to 500 at a time (`up to 500` ... the last batch might not be 500, depending on the limit you choose).

Comment: I tried your solution and got a weird result. I have a list of duplicated words ( more than 1000 in fact) which is not supposed to happen. Is it because I am calling the method from another class in another for loop as well? 
If you look at my edited post, there's some changes I added.

Comment: I guess what happened was based on your answer, the same word will be inserted to the table 10,000 times, followed by the second word for another 10,000 times. I guess if I set Limit =1 , that should fix the problem, at least the way I see it

Comment: One sensible approach would be to just pass a list or collection or words and paths.  Then, access the appropriate element during each iteration of the loop, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: Your solution does work but say for about 2,000 words, it takes 2 mins + while my solution above takes above 30 secs to complete ,only thing is it doesn't write to the table db.

Comment: Then this is not a meaningful benchmark comparison.  A meaningful comparison would be if your version took 30 seconds and worked.

Comment: I did pass my words and paths in my main method. You can have a look at my edited post.

Comment: Question: Is your current code working?  Is it doing all inserts to the table correctly?  If not, then it probably is not worth discussing further.

Comment: If everything is working, then may I ask why you opened a question here?

Comment: What I meant was it works if I didn't implement the ExecuteBatch method and when I  switched my way of doing it with this ExecuteBatch method, then it didn't work , hence the question posted here. Your answer provided certainly did solved my question. I hope everything is clear now

Comment: If you're asking why `executeBatch` is slower, then I don't know why.  But, keep in mind, that just because it is slower for _you_, in your Java code, does not mean that it puts more stress on the database.  To the contrary, by not making so frequent insert calls it may be less stressful for the database, which can be important for an application which hits its DB frequently.

Answer (score 1):

where is your loop. try this

```
 connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://126.32.3.20/fulltext_ltat?"
                        + "user=root&password=root&rewriteBatchedStatements=true");
```

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: Where is your loop and Your preparedStatement  must be out of loop

Comment: If then you move connection, preparedStatement your of your function

Comment: means how to make?